# Command Line equivalent to virt-manager GUI VM creation

Tags: kvm, libvirt, virt-manager

I have been using virt-manager to create KVM VMs on my Ubuntu 18.04.1 host.

I would like to now create the same VMs from the command line.  I customize the VMs before beginning installation - ie using UEFI firmware instead of BIOS for instance.

Is there an easy way to get the equivalent command line creation of VM?

Is there a log file they are written too?

Thanks

Densha

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `virt-install` and `virsh`. The formerncan install VMs from the command line and the latter can be used to send commands to libvirt either adhoc or as a shell